# How to open another application from Windows Cortana command?

Tags: uwp, cortana

We are writing some custom Cortana commands and have some basics working.  Now, we'd like to open a specific program from our command.  The program we're trying to open is a .NET framework application (we cannot convert it .NET Core).

We were hoping for some convenient equivalent to System.Diagnostics.Process.Start, but that doesn't seem to work here.

Any ideas on how we could kick off a program from our Cortana command?

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

UWP Apps has limited access to other apps and system. You can launch other app by specific protocol url (like callto:) or by share contract. Also you can communicate within several apps in one app bundle (like mail and calendar).

More information [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/app-to-app/index)

Answer (score -1):

Check here: http://www.cnet.com/how-to/the-complete-list-of-cortana-commands/ and here http://www.howtogeek.com/225458/15-things-you-can-do-with-cortana-on-windows-10/

Voice: "Cortana, Start Skype"

> On build 9926 Cortana does not have the ability to launch programs
>   with your voice.

Trouble?

Make sure you have Windows Search turned on, restart your computer with cortana turned off, and turn her back on once the PC has booted.

Its a service called "Windows Search."

Lastly: Reinstall program.